# Does it make sense to use MySQL 8 as JSON storage?

Tags: java, mysql, json, database, aws-documentdb

In our project we have a need to store some Java objects (with nesting level > 3) as JSONs because structure of this objects are often changed and this is really not convenient to use relational approach to store them.

We were considering different DBs to store objects as JSONs (we are using AWS):

- DynamoDB;
- DocumentDB;
- MySQL 8;

I was considering MySQL 8 as a most probable option because we already have MySQL DB configured and MySQL provided more data integrity because of ACID. But after week of investigation it is not still clear for me - should we consider MySQL 8 as the option at all ? Seems like it is proper for using for some small structures despite that MySQL offers a lot of functions to manipulate with JSON (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-functions.html)

Does anybody have any experience of using of MySql 8 as a main JSON storage ? Did you face any problem with it ? Or it makes sense to use DocumentDB/DynamoDB from the beginning ?

Comment: Your use case is just to store JSON objects? What about retrieving the data? Do you need flexible schema, flexible indexes? If you're working with JSON is probably best to use the right tool and start with a database that was designed to store in this format, at least that's what I would do.

Comment: @MihaiA Yes, I did thorough research (taking into account all what you've listed) and decided to proceed with DocumentDB. Thanks!